# Website hosted on 1and1 only display index.php

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess

I recently suscribed to a 1and1 hosting contract. I've been having issues to display my website, so I tried to put some very basic pages online in order to tell wether the issue was in my file or on the server side.
The homepage is named index.php and has a link to another page (page1.html) that is supposed to display a "Hello World".`

```
<a href="page1.html">Clique</a>
```

The homepage is online but there are some issues.

The homepage only works when it's called index.php and doesn't work when it's called index.html.
When I click on "Clique", the url changes to mywebsite.com/page1.html but the content is still "Clique" while it should be "Hello World".Also, the CSS file isn't read.

I've read a lot of threads dealing with similar issues and apparently it might be a problem with the .htaccess file. I don't have a .htaccess in the folder where my files are and I don't know much about how it works. Also, the CHMOD is 705 for both files.

Comment: Do you have any php inside index.html?

Comment: No I don't have any php

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the 1and1 support for this issue.

I don't think this is the right place to ask.

Do you have root access, or just FTP.

If there is no .htpasswd, try uploading one.
A generator which will help you is just one google away.

Comment: Thanks, I'll upload a .htpasswd. I called the customer service but they weren't able to help me. I just have a FTP  access.

Comment: You need to setup your own default page. Please just test to delete all files and then reupload your files.